# Whether to divide the web signup to steps or not?

Tags: signup-signon, multi-step

I have divided my signup page into a three-step signup:

1. Account info (username, password and email)
2. Personal Info (full name, gender and zip)
3. And lastly, telling the user to verify his/her email address

Is that really a good idea? As there are only six fields in the total signup process which will not seem to be tough for user at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only six input fields to fill, I would show all of them on the same page, but group the fields in the same your doing in your question.

A popular social network shows all fields on the signup page:

[image]

Comment: They use quite simple yet astounding design and experience. But my form looks quite bigger with all that padding and design. Also with 3 fields on 1st and 2nd step and at third step telling him to verify his email does looks good. But will it cause user to think that the form is too bulky?

Comment: @Cruze The only way to be sure is to test on your intended target audience.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't divide a such short form into separate steps - using descriptive headings should be enough.

Separating the fields into different views doesn't give any benefits, but can create confusion among the users. In addition, it needs more clutter to visualise the phases of the "wizard".

Comment: Actually with all the 6 fields in one page looked a bit long for me. I mean i would have thought that this is going to take time. But also by dividing into multiple steps i have a problem that it doesn't clears  how many more fields do i have to fill.